# Variadic template C2661

Tags: c++, stl, шаблоны-с++

Решил написать свой мини вектор и что то очень странная ошибка

> Error C2661   'MyVec::Init': no overloaded function takes 6 arguments

Сам код:

```
template <typename T, typename ... Args>
class MyVec
{
public:
    struct element {
        T cell;
        void* next;
    };
    element* head;

    MyVec(T first,Args ... arg)
    {
        element *list = new element();
        list->cell = first;
        list->next = NULL;
        head = list;
        Init(arg ...);
    }

    void Init(T now, Args ... arg)
    {
        element *list = new element();
        list->cell = now;
        element* next = head;
        while (!next.next)
            next = next->next;

        next = list;
        list.next = NULL;
        Init(arg ...); // вот здесь C2661
    }

     void Init(T now)
    {
        element *list = new element();
        list->cell = now;
        element* next = head;
        while (!next->next) {
            next = next->next;
        }
        next = list;
        list->next = NULL;
    }
};
void main()
{
   MyVec<int,int,int,int,int,int,int> p2(4,5,3,5,4,3,4);
}
```

Comment: А почему вы считаете эту ошибку "странной"? Вы сами предоставили лишь одну единственную функцию `Init` ровно для 7 аргументов. А потом пытаетесь вызывать ее с 6 аргументами. Функции для 6 аргументов вы не предоставили. Как это по-вашему должно работать?

Comment: Она же для неизвестного числа аргументов? Или во время компиляции она превращается в функцию для 6 аргументов?

Comment: @vados: Да. Неизвестно лишь количество аргументов шаблона, а количество аргументов функции у вас равно количеству аргументов шаблона.

Comment: @vados: Как только выполняется специализация шаблона класса с конкретными шаблонными аргументами, эта функция сразу же приобретает заранее известное фиксированное количество параметров.

Comment: у вас не вектор а список получается судя по реализации

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вам нужно определить целую серию функций `Init`. Для этого можно, по идее, воспользоваться вложенным шаблоном.

Привёл код в компилируемый вид, но там ещё ошибки времени выполнения (разыменование NULL), исправляйте.

```
#include <cstddef>

template <typename T, typename ... Args>
class MyVec
{
public:
    struct element {
        T cell;
        element* next;
    };
    element* head;

    MyVec(T first, Args ... arg)
    {
        element *list = new element();
        list->cell = first;
        list->next = NULL;
        head = list;
        Init(arg ...);
    }

    template <typename TInner, typename ... ArgsInner>
    void Init(TInner now, ArgsInner ... arg)
    {
        element *list = new element();
        list->cell = now;
        element* next = head;
        while (!next->next)
            next = next->next;

        next = list;
        list->next = NULL;
        Init(arg ...);
    }

    void Init(T now)
    {
        element *list = new element();
        list->cell = now;
        element* next = head;
        while (!next->next) {
            next = next->next;
        }
        next = list;
        list->next = NULL;
    }
};

int main()
{
    MyVec<int, int, int> p2(4, 5, 6);
}
```